# How to setup ANTLR in eclipse with gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, antlr

I'm reading [this article](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/?nabw=0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.it%2F) about setting up and using ANTLR in eclipse but I'm having trouble understanding the next sentence (in "4.1 Java Setup Using Gradle"):

> I use a Gradle plugin to invoke ANTLR and I also use the IDEA plugin
>   to generate the configuration for IntelliJ IDEA.

I've downloaded what I believe to be the eclipse equivilant of the plugin the writer is referring to and I've setup the project to use gradle to build.

I've added the following code to build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
archivesBaseName = 'someJar'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT' 

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.triemond.communicate.startup.Mainclass'
    }
}

dependencies {
   compile  'log4j:log4j:1.2.16'
}
```

However I don't understand what I need to do in order to follow the article. Could someone please explain me what the article is talking about in section 4.1?